# ReactJS Read URL parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom and according to docs it says for url pattern `https:\\example.com\user\:id\:gender`
we can use `useParams()` hook to read the patters like

```
import {useParams, Route} from react-router;

<Route exact path="/user/:id/:gender" component={User}/>

const user=(props)=>{
const params = useParams()
}

//params = {id:'1',gender:'f'}; output for url pattern >>> https:\\example.com\user\1\f
```

But in my case, I have two requirement

1. gender field is sometime required and some time not, then what changes needed in the Router?
2. How to read url pattern `https://example.com/user?id=1&gender=f` , because in this patter If I interchange the order then no effect will be on parameter object.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the params as follows and use them anywhere

```
const { id , gender } = useParams();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I need something else, there is difference between two pattern `example.com/user?id=1&gender=f` and `example.com\user\1\f `  how to read first one? @VH Aberyvickrama

Answer (score 0):

You need to use query params if you are trying to append optional data in URL as you discussed above.

you can simply use "useLocation()" hook provided by react-router-dom library to extract query params from any url.

```
// https://example.com/user?id=1&gender=f
import React from "react";

import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function QueryParamsDemo() {
  let query = useLocation().search;
  let getParams = () => console.log(query); // output will be {id:1,gender:"f"}
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getParams()}>Get Param</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```